# VirtueMart CurrencyDisplay Outside VirtueMart

Tags: php, joomla, currency, virtuemart

I need to get Rows calculations outside VirtueMart.
It can be done by:

```
  shopFunctionsF::calculateProductRowsHeights($products,$currency,$products_per_row);
```

I got $products, $products_per_row but don't know how to get $currency.
If I print out $currency at templates/My template/html/com_virtuemart/sublayouts/products.php I get CurrencyDisplay Object.

And class CurrencyDisplay can't be reached from outside.
Any ideas what to send instead CurrencyDisplay Object. Or how to get it outside?